# First time MapReduce: I need to combine a distinct and count, please help

Tags: sql, mapreduce

I have a collection and need to get a distinct count from the data set in MongoDB

`db['2011-05-29'].distinct("plugins.HTTPServer.string");`

returns all the distinct names for the key

How would I go about getting a count for every occurrence of a particular string?

Example:

```
Apache 29172
IIS 3932
```

I've looked at some MapReduce examples but can't seem to get it to work right. As my counts add up to more than the actual items in the collection.

```
db['2011-04-13-1pm-scan'].distinct("plugins.HTTPServer.string").length;
```

returns the number of distinct items in that key.

I however want the Key Value and Count for each, as above.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is 100% exactly what the wordcount demo application does.
It's part of the standard set of examples shipped with Hadoop and it's also explained here in great detail in these pages

1. http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount
2. http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#wordcount

HTH

Comment: My bad, I should've been more specific, stating that I'm looking for a Map Reduce function in MongoDB.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/README.md